# Generating unique ids via PHP for use in document.getelementID?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to use php to go through an array via a for loop. I'd like to create objects of each of the items in the for loop, and when the objects are clicked, they'll turn into a different color. To do so, I'm using document.getElementId() which requires unique IDs. I've tried to generate these unique IDs as per below, but it seems that when I click the object, it's not changing color so the ID isn't exactly working. Here's the code below:

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
<button class = "answerchoice" id="c1"+<?php echo $i; ?>><?php echo $data['C1']; ?></button>
<script>
  document.getElementById("c1"+[<?php echo $i; ?>]).onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("c1"+[<?php echo $i; ?>]).style.backgroundColor = "#abebbd";}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting is slightly off. The `echo $i` needs to be inside the quotes for the id attribute. The plus sign is also extraneous(you are not concatenating here, the value is literally being output. Additionally, in PHP, concatenation is performed with the "." operator).

```php
<button class = "answerchoice" id="c1<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $data['C1']; ?></button>
```

You may also consider the alternate echo syntax which is more concise.

```php
<button class = "answerchoice" id="c1<?= $i ?>"><?php echo $data['C1']; ?></button>
```

Additionally, you could benefit from assigning the id to a local variable rather than rebuilding it in three places. The same could apply to selecting the element in JavaScript(`var button=document.getElementById(...)`).

Comment: Thank you so much! That easily solved the problem :)